# How to delete user data from realtime database when account removed?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code for adding an eventlistener to a button for removing an account and its data from the database:

```
removeAccountBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    deleteUser(auth.currentUser)
    .then(() => {
        set(uidRef, null)
        .catch((error) => {
            alert(error.message);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code == "auth/requires-recent-login") {
            alert("You have been signed in for a too long time to delete your account, please sign out and sign back in. Try again after that.");
        }
    });
});
```

So I am using the firebase realtime database and javascript with firebase 9 (modular) syntax. Whenever someone creates an account, the user's information is put to the database to a node with the name of the current users uid (accessed with uidRef variable).

The problem is that when deleteUser works, it goes to the .then part of the code. There it should remove the user's data from the database, but if that does not work for one reason or another, the user data will just stay in the database.

And if I were to change the order, basically make the code remove the data from the database first and only after that remove the account, then there the problem is that it might remove the user information from the database but it may not successfully remove the account.

I asked chatgpt for a solution several times, and it gave me these pieces of code:

```
removeAccountBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let dataDeletionPromise = set(uidRef, null);
    
    deleteUser(auth.currentUser)
    .then(() => {
        return dataDeletionPromise;
    })
    .then(() => {
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code === "auth/requires-recent-login") {
            alert("You have been signed in for too long to delete your account. Please sign out and sign back in. Try again after that.");
        } else {
            alert(error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

And

```
removeAccountBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const batch = writeBatch(database);

    batch.delete(uidRef);

    batch.commit()
        .then(() => {
            return deleteUser(auth.currentUser);
        })
        .then(() => {})
        .catch((error) => {
            if (error.code === "auth/requires-recent-login") {
                alert("You have been signed in for too long to delete your account. Please sign out and sign back in. Try again after that.");
            } else {
                alert(error.message);
            }
        });
});
```

The first one is some kind of promise thing, but chatgpt said it works just like the code I have. The second one apparently is only for firestore.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you share the value of `uidRef`? Also do you get an error? *(Comment not written by ChatGPT)*

Comment: Do you have any security rules on your database, for example requiring that the user can only access their own data?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Renaud and Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 0):

The current problems you are facing are not only with the code but with the logic.

In scenario 1 when you are first deleting the user from auth module and then trying to delete the data from Realtime Database I asume you are having handler checking if user is logged or not and redirecting to the login page or security rules for making writes (creations, updates or deletes) only when user is logged.
In that scenario your app will redirect you before the operation finishes in some cases or will not allow it at all because the user no longer existing/logged.

In scenario 2 it when you are first deleting the user from Realtime Database and then from auth module you cannot ensure if customer will not close the session before the  deletion user from auth module.

You have 2 safe options which will achieve 100% success rate no matter what, but unfortunately they require opting for Blaze plan (not a big deal you will still have all free perks from the Spark plan - you can check here the pricing: https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

1. **Delete User Data** extension works for Cloud Firestore, Realtime Database and Cloud Storage -
   No coding required: https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/delete-user-data
2. **Cloud Firestore function triggers** - requires coding: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion

For 1st option you simply need to setup the plugin and point him to the fields and pretty much will take care of the rest.

For 2nd option you can create trigger function when user is removed from auth module and to delete also the relevant data from Realtime Database. The only drawback from using this method is that function is fired only on single user even, is not supporting currently multiple user invocations.

> Caution: Deleting multiple users at once using the Firebase Admin SDK (for example, admin.auth().deleteUsers([uid1, uid2]) in Node.js) does not fire user deletion events, so event handlers set up using functions.auth.user().onDelete() will not be triggered. Delete users one at a time if you want user deletion events to fire for each deleted user.

I hope I've helped, good luck!